# Leaflet Change Icon in Angular Script

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How to change icon in Leaflet in Angular JS

Icon to be change in `$scope.map.markers.push`

Code i tried so far:

```
$cordovaGeolocation
        .getCurrentPosition()
        .then(function (position) {
          $scope.loading = false;
          $scope.map.center.lat  = position.coords.latitude;
          $scope.map.center.lng = position.coords.longitude;
          $scope.map.center.zoom = 18;
          $scope.map.markers.now = {
            lat:position.coords.latitude,
            lng:position.coords.longitude,
            focus: true,            
            draggable: false,
            message: 'You are here'
          };

          $scope.map.markers.push = {
            lat:19.0310968,
            lng:73.030836,
            focus: false,            
            draggable: false,
            //url: "http://localhost/uxo_data/img/covered.png",
            styles: [{
                url: "http://localhost/uxo_data/img/covered.png",
                width:60,
                height:60,
                textColor: 'white',
                textSize: 14,
                fontFamily: 'Open Sans'
            }],
            //message: ''
          };

        },
        function(err) {
          // error
          console.log("Location error!");
          console.log(err);

        });
```

No Console Errors in above code!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using angular leaflet directive or some other angular+leaflet? If the former, see: https://github.com/tombatossals/angular-leaflet-directive/blob/master/doc/markers-attribute.md where it shows that you may not need the styles attribute but just to set iconUrl